# in boost iostream filtering_ostream, what is the difference between sync(), strict_sync() and flush()?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, boost-iostreams

considering a simple counting filter:

```
class CountableOstreamFilter : public boost::iostreams::multichar_output_filter {
public:
    CountableOstreamFilter(): m_written(0) { 
    }

    template<typename Sink>
    std::streamsize write(Sink& dest, const char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
            auto result  = boost::iostreams::write(dest, s, n);
            assert(n == result);
            m_written += result;
            return result;
    }

    inline std::streamsize writtenBytes() const {
        return m_written;
    }

private:
    std::streamsize m_written;
};
```

and using it thus:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream counted_cout;
counted_cout.push(CountableOstreamFilter());
counted_cout.push(std::cout);
counted_cout << "hello world";
```

what would be the difference between calling sync(), strict_sync() or flush()?
    counted_cout.sync();        // what is different from this call
    counted_cout.strict_sync(); // to this call
    counted_cout.flush();       // to this call?

I'm using boost 1.50.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference between `sync`, `strict_sync`, and `flush` is their return values.  All 3 of them .  All of them call the flush method on any Filter or Device that's part of the `filtering_stream` that satisfies the [Flushable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/flushable.html) concept.  Any Filter/Device that does not support the Flushable concept is simply skipped.

`sync` returns true unless one of the Flushable Filters/Devices returns false.  This means that if there are non-Flushable Filters/Devices that are part of the `filtering_stream`, data could get stuck in them, but `sync` would return true, since they are not Flushable.

`strict_sync` is similar, except if it encounters a non-Flushable Filter/Device.  In this case, `strict_sync` will return false, even though all of the Flushable Filters/Devices might return true.  The reason for this is so that a caller of `strict_sync` knows that if it returns true, all of the data was successfully flushed.

The member `flush` simply returns a reference to the stream,effectively discarding whether or not the flush was successful.  The non-member `flush` [has it's own rules for what it returns depending on the input value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/flush.html)

In your case, the `CountableOstreamFilter` is not Flushable (it's not convertible to the necessary flushable_tag).  Hence, calls to `sync` will return true as long as the flush on the underlying stream is successful.  However, `strict_sync` should return false.